# Measuring Current with a Shunt Resistor and an In-Amp

Tags: measurement, shunt

I'm building a device to acquire current data through an appliance. The schematic can be seen below:

[image]

The problem is that I need this measurement to be step up tenfold, but I added a 2.5V reference just to make sure that the measurement stays within the 0V-5V range.

If I just use a gain op-amp, then the offset is also going to be step up tenfold, and the new offset would be 25V right?

How can I fix this?

**in response to comment by @Neil_UK**
Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using an in amp with a reference input?

Comment: When you say "outlet" do you mean a mains power socket? When you say "isolation" do you mean this device should prevent electrocution of users handling the Arduino circuit?

Comment: Because I need an isolated in-amp for safety

Comment: Precisely, The Photon

Comment: You add a second op-amp at the differential output that biases the signal at 2.5V.

Comment: You might want to draw supply pins 1 and 4 on the left hand side of the package, to make it clear what the isolation function is!

Answer (score 1):

As the ISO130 has a common mode output of about 2.4v, and low impedance outputs that can supply 1mA, the following diff-amp will work

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftlFpl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will give you 10:1 differential gain following the isolation amplifier. The voltage between ADC input and ADC ref will be 10x that between the OUT +/- pins. The ADC ref terminal can be taken to any convenient voltage that's good for the ADC.

Comment: thanks, Neil_UK! In reality, I'm using an AMC1200/B Fully-Differential Isolation Amplifier. But I believe your idea should work for it as well

Comment: Shouldn't the reference be at Out -?

Comment: @William why would you want to do that? Do you know how a diff-amp like that works? Have you read the 130 data sheet (though I take no responsibility for being told by the OP after my reply that it's a 120, not a 130!)? I've explained in my answer that the 10x output occurs between the ADC input and ADC ref pins.